# Read multiple text files and import each of them as columns

Tags: matlab

I have a code but I have no idea how to get each of the text files to be placed as different columns in a matrix.

For example, I have 5 text files and all of them have only one column.  How can I get each of their columns into a single matrix?  The code I wrote is below but it isn't working:

```
for k = 1:5
 textFilename = ['file' num2str(k) '.txt'];
 fid = fopen(textFilename, 'rt');
 textData = fread(fid);
 fclose(fid);
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that the data read in from all of the text files are the same length.  If that's the case, then all you have to do is create an empty matrix, then concatenate your results column by column.  You simply have to add two lines.

```
 % Store the text data here
 textDataMatrix = [];
 for k = 1:5
  textFilename = ['file' num2str(k) '.txt'];
  fid = fopen(textFilename, 'rt');
  textData = fread(fid);
  % Concatenate text file data by column
  textDataMatrix = [textDataMatrix textData];
  fclose(fid);
 end
```

At the end of this script, `textDataMatrix` will contain the text data that you wanted and placed in separate columns as you desired.

---

**NB:** It is usually poor practice to create an empty matrix and populate your items after as it is considered slow.  It will help if you actually know how many characters / bytes / numbers are in a single data file before running this code.  When you do that, you can preallocate the right amount of memory you need before you run through the `for` loop.  Creating the right amount of space before populating the matrix is more efficient in MATLAB instead of concatenating elements.  If you want to do it this way, suppose that the number of elements you have in a data file is called `numElements`.  You would rewrite the code I wrote above in the following way:

```
 % Store the text data here
 textDataMatrix = zeros(numElements, 5);
 for k = 1:5
  textFilename = ['file' num2str(k) '.txt'];
  fid = fopen(textFilename, 'rt');
  textData = fread(fid);
  % Place the k'th text data in the k'th column
  textDataMatrix(:,k) = textData;
  fclose(fid);
 end
```

However, if there aren't that many elements in a particular text file, then the first version of the code I have above will be just fine.

Comment: thanks... so if I want to store the 2nd column of each file just store it like this: x = txtData(:,2); and disp(x) to view the values

Comment: sorry I got this error when I tried it: Cannot find an exact (case-sensitive) match for 'numElements'

The closest match is: numelements in C:\Program
Files\MATLAB\R2013a\toolbox\nnet\nnet\nndatafun\numelements.m


Error in project (line 2)
 textDataMatrix = zeros(numElements, 5);

Comment: If you read my post carefully, that's **assuming** you already know the number of elements in your file.  If you don't, then you can only use the first version of the code.  You have no choice but to concatenate each column as per the first version.

Comment: number of elements you mean the columns in the files?

Comment: Number of elements meaning how many rows of the data exist in each of the file.  For example, if a text file had 10 numbers in each file, then `numElements = 10`.... but if you don't know this, then use the first version of the code.  It will work **without** knowing how many data elements a file has.