# Is there a way to combine columns from multiple text files into a single text file using Matlab?

Tags: matlab, text

I'm using Matlab to combine columns from 4 individual text files into a single new text file in Matlab.  Each text file has the same number of rows (5478).  I found this similar issue here...

[Read multiple text files and import each of them as columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23051764/read-multiple-text-files-and-import-each-of-them-as-columns/59724682#59724682)

I took Ray's second suggestion from that link, but it still did not work.  My code looks like the following...

```
 textDataMatrix = zeros(5478, 4);
 t = {'prec', 'rsds', 'tmax', 'tmin'};

  for k = 1:4
    Mead_NE_Climate_1985_1999 = [t{k} '_outfile_mead.txt'];
    fid = fopen(Mead_NE_Climate_1985_1999, 'rt');
    textData = fread(fid);
% Place the k'th text data in the k'th column
  textDataMatrix(:,k) = textData;
  fclose(fid);
 end
```

For some reason, I get the following error...

Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in Mead_Text_Climate (line 10)
  textDataMatrix(:,k) = textData;

I have visually inspected all of the text files, and they each have the same number of rows/lines.  So I'm struggling to understand why this isn't working.  Can anyone help?  Thanks for your time!
[First few lines containing daily Precipitation Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RQYn.png)

Comment: Can you show us your text files? Please have them available somewhere for us to look at.

Comment: Sounds like `textData = fread(fid)` isn't producing what you'd like it to. Have you checked what it **is** producing?

Comment: @MarkSnyder:  You are correct.  textData becomes a 58819x1 matrix filled with numbers that I do not recognize.  The numbers in textData are whole numbers which don't resemble numbers that are in each of the text files.  So I'm not sure why that is.

Comment: @rayryeng-ReinstateMonica, Thanks for the quick responses! I don't really use Google Drive much, so I hope this works so you can access the text files...drive.google.com/open?id=1CEh6u680Sp5NCYGQJBxBoqtGJCW3ByVA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`readmatrix`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readmatrix.html) instead.  What's nice about this function is that it can handle `NaN` values, which is what some of your text files have.  Also, because your text files have commas, this will confuse the function and think there is a second empty column.  Just subset into the first column to be safe.  Please note that this function exists in version 2019a or greater:

```
textDataMatrix = zeros(5478, 4);
t = {'prec', 'rsds', 'tmax', 'tmin'};
for k = 1:4
    Mead_NE_Climate_1985_1999 = [t{k} '_outfile_mead.txt'];
    textData = readmatrix(Mead_NE_Climate_1985_1999);
    textDataMatrix(:,k) = textData(:,1);
end
```

Comment: When I use dlmread, I get the following error: "Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts
Error in Mead_Text_Climate (line 7)
  textDataMatrix(:,k) = textData;"       Before the script stops, it shows that textData is a 5478x2 array.  The first column appears to be reading the correct text data from prec txt file.  However, it hangs up between the prec txt file and the rsds txt file for some reason (column 2 reads 0's) .  Initially, the last entry in the first text file did not have a comma, so I added one, but that didn't help.  Any Ideas?

Comment: @AliKoleiny If you're using MATLAB R2019a or greater, you can safely use `readmatrix`.  `dlmread` and `fscanf` cannot handle `NaN` values but `readmatrix` can.  The commas also throw off the function because it thinks there is a second column.  You can subset and just get the first column.  I've edited my post - please have a look.

Comment: Sorry I'm just now getting back to you Ray.  Unfortunately, my version is R2017b.  If you have a minute, do you have any suggestions for how I can treat the NaN values in that version?  Also, I'm not sure entirely what you mean by "you can subset and just get the first column".  I assume that allows MATLAB to ignore the commas.  But I'm not sure how "you can subset".  Any additional insight would be appreciated!

Comment: I've already mentioned how to do that in my post above. Unfortunately I don't have more time to spare. I'm going to leave this to someone else. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

`fread` reads files as binary even though you `fopen` your files in text mode. The output is a vector of bytes (but stored as doubles). (See [matlab doc for fread](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html))

Instead, you want to use a different method to read your file as text, such as [fscanf](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fscanf.html).

Assuming the data in your files is floating point numbers (and have a comma at the end of each row), the following should do what you want:

```
textDataMatrix = zeros(5478, 4);
t = {'prec', 'rsds', 'tmax', 'tmin'};

for k = 1:4
   Mead_NE_Climate_1985_1999 = [t{k} '_outfile_mead.txt'];
   fid = fopen(Mead_NE_Climate_1985_1999, 'rt');
   textData = fscanf(fid, '%f,');
   textDataMatrix(:,k) = textData;
   fclose(fid);
end
```

Comment: Emrah, I used fscanf instead of fread as you suggested.  When I did this, textDataMatrix (which is a 5478x4 matrix) took the first row value from each text file, and repeated it for each subsequent value for the entire column, for each column (text file).                                                                                                                                  For some reason, it just repeated the first value in each text file (in textDataMatrix), instead of correctly adding the remaining values from each of the individual text files.  Do you know why that is the case?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know why it would do that without seeing what's in the files. Can you post what's in one of the files here? Not all 5000+ rows but maybe the first 5 rows of each file or something?

Comment: I added an image at the bottom of my original post.  Those are daily values of precipitation from the first text file.  Unfortunately I have to step away from my laptop for a couple hours, but I should be able to check back later.  If you're busy, don't worry about it.  You've been quite helpful already.  I appreciate all your help!

Comment: Oh the issue is that your rows have a `,` at the end which needs to be accounted for to get `fscanf` to work correctly. I updated my answer to include the comma, see if it works for you now (fscanf should also correctly handle the rows that have values using `e` notation)